# Add a new column with same value for every group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format

```
 id   name   zip
 123  aaa    614
 123  nnn    615
 341  yun    318
 441  ros    911
```

For every group of unique id, I create a new column based on the column id. Below is the code for that, but instead of creating the same uuid for a similar id, it creates different ones.

```
 df_complete = pd.DataFrame([])
 for new_id in df['id'].unique():
    df_interim = df[df['id'] == new_id]
    df_interim['uuid'] = df_interim['id'].apply(lambda _: uuid.uuid4())
    df_complete.append(df_interim)
```

Expected output:

```
 id   name   zip   uuid
 123  aaa    614   uuid_1
 123  nnn    615   uuid_1
 341  yun    318   uuid_2
 441  ros    911   uuid_3
```

Any leads or suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) and call the `uuid` function within [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html), as follows:

[`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) helps to set the same value (uuid) for all entries in the same group (same `id`).

```
df['uuid'] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform(lambda _: uuid.uuid4())
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)


    id name  zip                                  uuid
0  123  aaa  614  e7d7c519-52e0-486f-99f2-722b73c16242
1  123  nnn  615  e7d7c519-52e0-486f-99f2-722b73c16242
2  341  yun  318  dc24c9d0-4c52-44ab-ac19-c6ce64fed5b7
3  441  ros  911  0a14dc45-cbe7-43aa-8b54-90ef88ca8a7e
```